# How to speed up or vectorize a for loop?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization, rcpp

I would like to increase the speed of my for loop via vectorization or using Data.table or something else. I have to run the code on 1,000,000 rows and my code is really slow.

The code is fairly self-explanatory. I have included an explanation below just in case. I have included the input and the output of the function. Hopefully you will help me make the function faster.

**My** **goal** is to bin the vector "Volume", where each bin is equal to 100 shares. The vector "Volume" contains the number of shares traded. Here is what it looks like:

```
head(Volume, n = 60)
[1]  5  3  1  5  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 18  1  1 18  2  7 13  2  7 13  3  2  1  1  3  2  1  1  1
[32]  1  6  6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 18  2  1  1  2  1 14 18  2  1  1  2  1 14  1  1  9  5
```

The vector "binIdexVector" is the same length of "Volume", and it contains the bin number; that is each element of the first 100 shares get the number 1, each elements of the next 100 shares get the number 2, each elements of the next 100 shares get the number 3, and so on. Here is what that vector looks like:

```
 head(binIdexVector, n = 60)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[48] 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Here is **my function**:

```
#input as a vector
Volume<-c(5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 
                   18L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 2L, 1L, 
                   1L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 18L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 
                   2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                   10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                   1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
                   1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                   1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                   10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)

binIdexVector <- numeric(length(Volume))

# initialize 
binIdex <-1
totalVolume <-0

for(i in seq_len(length(Volume))){

  totalVolume <- totalVolume + Volume[i]  

  if (totalVolume <= 100) {

    binIdexVector[i] <- binIdex

  } else {

    binIdex <- binIdex + 1
    binIdexVector[i] <- binIdex
    totalVolume <- Volume[i]
  }
}

# output:
> dput(binIdexVector)
c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
  1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
  3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
  4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
  9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Thank a lot for your help!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Rcpp when vectorization is difficult.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
  IntegerVector bin(NumericVector Volume, int n) {
    IntegerVector binIdexVector(Volume.size());
    int binIdex = 1;
    double totalVolume =0;

    for(int i=0; i<Volume.size(); i++){
      totalVolume = totalVolume + Volume[i];
      if (totalVolume <= n) {
        binIdexVector[i] = binIdex;
      } else {
        binIdex++;
        binIdexVector[i] = binIdex;
        totalVolume = Volume[i];
      }
    }
    return binIdexVector;
  }')

all.equal(bin(Volume, 100), binIdexVector)
#[1] TRUE
```

It's faster than `findInterval(cumsum(Volume), seq(0, sum(Volume), by=100))` (which of course gives an inexact answer)

Comment: thank you very much. I ran it on 5 millions rows. My function takes 10.62 sec and yours take a whopping 0.063 secs. That's amazing! Thanks again

Comment: Actually this is your function. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Volume<-sample(1:5,500,replace=TRUE)
binLabels<- cumsum(diff(cumsum(Volume) %% 100) <0) + 1
```

This results in the vector `binLabels` which indicates which bin each data point belongs to. Each bin will hold the number of data points required such that the sum of the data points is 100.

Comment: Hi Keegan, thank you for your help. When I run binLabels on the vector Volume in my code, I don't get the same output as in binIdexVector. Using your function, the labels starts at 0 and end at 4, while my output starts at 1 and ends at 10. Can you run your function of the Volume vector in my code and see the difference? Again thank you for your help

Comment: right, I've made a change to mine. Quick question about yours - don't you want `totalVolume` to reset to 0 every time it surpasses 100? So the `totalVolume<-0` should be inside the loop? Or am I misunderstanding the goal?

Comment: once it surpasses 100, the function goes into the "else" part. I want totalVolume to be equal to the next row and start adding from there. If  totalVolume<-0 is inside the loop, the row that surpasses 100 will not be added, and the loop will go on the next row.

Comment: so to be clear, you want to add up the elements of Volume, and every time that sum surpasses 100, you create a new bin? I think you'll find `cumsum()` useful for doing this without a for loop.

Comment: @keen, I am gonna look into cumsum(). I ran your code and it still doesn't match my output :( Thank you for your effort though, I appreciate