# creating the page break after every 16 rows considering the category and sub-category

Tags: r

I am facing a challenge in creating the page break after every 16 rows considering the category and sub-category. consider that we have the data as below where category is `row_label1` and sub_category is `row_label2`.

I have created the groups for every 16 rows as an increment.

```r
structure(list(row_label1 = c("Age (years)", "Age (years)", "Age (years)", 
"Age (years)", "Age range, n(%)", "Age range, n(%)", "Age range, n(%)", 
"Race, n(%)", "Race, n(%)", "Race, n(%)", "Gender, n(%)", "Gender, n(%)", 
"Ethnicity, n(%)", "Ethnicity, n(%)", "Height (cm)", "Height (cm)", 
"Height (cm)", "Height (cm)", "Weight (kg)", "Weight (kg)", "Weight (kg)", 
"Weight (kg)", "Body Mass Index (kg/m2)", "Body Mass Index (kg/m2)", 
"Body Mass Index (kg/m2)", "Body Mass Index (kg/m2)", "BMI (kg/m2)", 
"BMI (kg/m2)", "BMI (kg/m2)"), row_label2 = c("n", "Mean (SD)", 
"Median", "Min, Max", "<65", "65-80", ">80", "WHITE", "BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN", 
"AMERICAN INDIAN OR ALASKA NATIVE", "Female", "Male", "Hispanic or latino", 
"Not hispanic or latino", "n", "Mean (SD)", "Median", "Min, Max", 
"n", "Mean (SD)", "Median", "Min, Max", "n", "Mean (SD)", "Median", 
"Min, Max", "<25", "25-<30", ">=30"), groups = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -29L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a new variable which also takes into consideration the category and sub category and then increments the number so that the category and sub-category does not split between 2 pages

[image]

now I want to have the new variable to increment considering the 16 rows , but with category and sub-category should not split. so here in the new variable the number 2 should start before the Height though it is short of 16 rows considering the category and sub-category

I am expecting a page variable something as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531568/conditional-cumsum-with-reset):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(n=if_else(row_number()==1,n(),0L),.by=row_label1) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_16 = purrr::accumulate(n, ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 16, .x + .y, .y)),
         pageno= cumsum(n == cumsum_16))

# A tibble: 20 x 6
   row_label1      row_label2                       groups     n cumsum_16   pageno
   <chr>           <chr>                             <int> <int>     <int>    <int>
 1 Age (years)     n                                     1     4         4        1
 2 Age (years)     Mean (SD)                             1     0         4        1
 3 Age (years)     Median                                1     0         4        1
 4 Age (years)     Min, Max                              1     0         4        1
 5 Age range, n(%) <65                                   1     3         7        1
 6 Age range, n(%) 65-80                                 1     0         7        1
 7 Age range, n(%) >80                                   1     0         7        1
 8 Race, n(%)      WHITE                                 1     3        10        1
 9 Race, n(%)      BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN             1     0        10        1
10 Race, n(%)      AMERICAN INDIAN OR ALASKA NATIVE      1     0        10        1
11 Gender, n(%)    Female                                1     2        12        1
12 Gender, n(%)    Male                                  1     0        12        1
13 Ethnicity, n(%) Hispanic or latino                    1     2        14        1
14 Ethnicity, n(%) Not hispanic or latino                1     0        14        1
15 Height (cm)     n                                     1     4         4        2
16 Height (cm)     Mean (SD)                             1     0         4        2
17 Height (cm)     Median                                2     0         4        2
18 Height (cm)     Min, Max                              2     0         4        2
19 Weight (kg)     n                                     2     4         8        2
20 Weight (kg)     Mean (SD)                             2     0         8        2
...
```