# Create grouping based on cumulative sum and another group

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

This question is nearly identical to:
[Create new group based on cumulative sum and group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621852/create-new-group-based-on-cumulative-sum-and-group)

However, when I apply the accepted solution to my data, it doesn't have the expected result.

In a nutshell, I have a data with two variables: `domain` and `value`. `Domain` is a group variable with multiple observations and `value` is some continuous value that I would like to accumulate by `domain` and great a new group variable, `newgroup`. There are three main rules:

1. I accumulate only within each `domain`. If I reach the end of the `domain`, then the accumulation is reset.
2. If the accumulated sum is at least 1.0 then the observations whose values added up to at least 1.0 are assigned to a different value for `group1`. Please note that this rule can be satisfied by a single observation.
3. If the last group in a `domain` has an accumulated sum less than 1.0, then merge that with the second to last group within the same `domain`. This is reflected in the variable `group2`

The data below has been simplified. The data will usually consist of 10^5 - 10^6 rows, so a vectorized solution would be ideal.

**Example Data**

```
domain <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,8))
value <- c(1,0,2,2.5,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.2,0.6,0,0,0.1)
df_raw <- data.frame(domain,value)


 domain value
      1   1.0
      1   0.0
      1   2.0
      1   2.5
      1   0.1
      2   0.1
      2   0.5
      2   0.0
      2   0.2
      2   0.6
      2   0.0
      2   0.0
      2   0.1
```

**Desired Output**

```
cumsum_val <- c(1,0,2,2.5,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.6,0.8,1.4,0,0,0.1)
group1 <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6)
group2 <- c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4) #Satisfies Rule #3
df_want <- data.frame(domain,value,cumsum_val,group1,group2)

 domain value cumsum_val group1 group2
      1   1.0        1.0      1      1
      1   0.0        0.0      2      2
      1   2.0        2.0      2      2
      1   2.5        2.5      3      3
      1   0.1        0.1      4      3
      2   0.1        0.1      5      4
      2   0.5        0.6      5      4
      2   0.0        0.6      5      4
      2   0.2        0.8      5      4
      2   0.6        1.4      5      4
      2   0.0        0.0      6      4
      2   0.0        0.0      6      4
      2   0.1        0.1      6      4
```

I used the following code:

```
sum0 <- function(x, y) { if (x + y >= 1.0) 0 else x + y }
is_start <- function(x) head(c(TRUE, Reduce(sum0, init=0, x, acc = TRUE)[-1] == 0), -1)
cumsum(ave(df_raw$value, df_raw$domain, FUN = is_start))
## 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 8 9
```

but the last line does not produce the same values as `group1` above. Generating `group1` output is what is mainly causing me issues. Can someone help me understand the function `is_start` and how that is supposed to produce the groupings?

**EDIT**
`akrun` provided some working code in the comments for the simplified example above. However, there are still some situations where it doesn't work. For example,

```
domain <- c(rep(1,7),rep(2,8))
value <- c(1,0,1,0,2,2.5,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.2,0.6,0,0,0.1)
df_raw <- data.frame(domain,value)
```

The output is show below with `new` coming from `akrun`'s code and `group1` and `group2` are the desired groupings based on rules #2 and #3. The discrepancy between `new` and `group2` occurs mainly in the first 3 rows.

```
 domain value new group1 group2
      1   1.0   1      1      1
      1   0.0   2      2      2
      1   1.0   3      2      2
      1   0.0   4      3      3
      1   2.0   4      3      3
      1   2.5   5      4      4
      1   0.1   5      5      4
      2   0.1   6      6      5
      2   0.5   6      6      5
      2   0.0   6      6      5
      2   0.2   6      6      5
      2   0.6   6      6      5
      2   0.0   6      7      5
      2   0.0   6      7      5
      2   0.1   6      7      5
```

**EDIT 2**
I have updated with a working answer.

Comment: @akrun Yes, I've updated the post to be more clear about what I'm asking. I changed the data example to the "swapped" version.

Comment: Yes, ultimately, but generating `group1` is what is causing me issues.

Comment: When it is in row 2, 1 +0 = 1 which satisifies >=1, so, it is assigned new ID in group1, in the third row, isn't it still `0 +2 = 2` which satisfies >=1, -> group2 = 3?

Comment: May be `df_want %>% group_by(domain) %>% mutate(new = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(value)))<= 1), new = if(n_distinct(new) == n()) 1 else new) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(new = rleid(new))`

Comment: Since row 1 met rule #2, the row 2 should have a new value for `group1` and `group2`. It shouldn't be cumulative with row 1. Row 2 doesn't satisfy any conditions, but when it is added with row 3, rule #2 is satisfied. Since rows 2 and 3 were added together to satisfy rule #2, they should be in the same `group1` and `group2`

Comment: @akrun, yes that does work for this case, but when I apply it to my data, it still fails in some instances. E.g. If I repeat the first two rows, it fails to do the grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works! It uses a combination of purrr's `accumulate` (similar to cumsum but more versatile) and `cumsum` with appropriate use of `group_by` to get what you're looking for. I've added comments to indicate what each part is doing. I'll note that next_group2 is a bit of a misnomer--it's more of a not_next_group2, but hopefully the rest is clear.

```
library(tidyverse)

domain <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,8))
value <- c(1,0,2,2.5,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.2,0.6,0,0,0.1)
df_raw <- data.frame(domain,value)

## Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076769/dplyr-r-cumulative-sum-with-reset
sum_reset_at = function(val_col, threshold, include.equals = TRUE) {
  if (include.equals) {
    purrr::accumulate({{val_col}}, ~if_else(.x>=threshold , .y, .x+.y))
  } else {
    purrr::accumulate({{val_col}}, ~if_else(.x>threshold , .y, .x+.y))
  }
}

df_raw %>% 
  group_by(domain) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum_val = sum_reset_at(value, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(next_group1 = ifelse(lag(cumsum_val) >= 1 | row_number() == 1, 1, 0)) %>% ## binary interpretation of whether there should be a new group
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(group1 = cumsum(next_group1)) %>% ## generate new groups
  group_by(domain, group1) %>%
  mutate(next_group2 = ifelse(max(cumsum_val) < 1 & row_number() == 1, 1, 0)) %>% ## similar to above, but grouped by your new group1; we ask it only to transition at the first value of the group that doesn't reach 1
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(group2 = cumsum(next_group1 - next_group2)) %>% ## cancel out the next_group1 binary if it meets the conditions of next_group2
  select(-starts_with("next_"))
```

And as specified, this produces:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   domain value cumsum_val group1 group2
    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      1   1          1        1      1
 2      1   0          0        2      2
 3      1   2          2        2      2
 4      1   2.5        2.5      3      3
 5      1   0.1        0.1      4      3
 6      2   0.1        0.1      5      4
 7      2   0.5        0.6      5      4
 8      2   0          0.6      5      4
 9      2   0.2        0.8      5      4
10      2   0.6        1.4      5      4
11      2   0          0        6      4
12      2   0          0        6      4
13      2   0.1        0.1      6      4
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is adapted from [Group vector on conditional sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549992/group-vector-on-conditional-sum).

**Helper Rcpp Function**

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
IntegerVector CreateGroup(NumericVector x, int cutoff) {
    IntegerVector groupVec (x.size());
    int group = 1;
    int threshid = 0;
    double runSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        runSum += x[i];
        groupVec[i] = group;

        if (runSum >= cutoff) {
            group++;
            runSum = 0;
        }
    }
    return groupVec;
}
')
```

**Main Function**

```
domain <- c(rep(1,7),rep(2,8))
value <- c(1,0,1,0,2,2.5,0.1,0.1,0.5,0,0.2,0.6,0,0,0.1)
df_raw <- data.frame(domain,value)

df_raw %>%
  group_by(domain) %>%
  mutate(group1 = CreateGroup(value,1),
         group1 = ifelse(group1==max(group1) & last(value) < 1,
                        max(group1)-1,group1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group1))

 domain value group1 group2
      1   1.0      1      1
      1   0.0      2      2
      1   1.0      2      2
      1   0.0      3      3
      1   2.0      3      3
      1   2.5      4      4
      1   0.1      4      4
      2   0.1      1      5
      2   0.5      1      5
      2   0.0      1      5
      2   0.2      1      5
      2   0.6      1      5
      2   0.0      1      5
      2   0.0      1      5
      2   0.1      1      5
```